# Why does Rails use HashWithIndifferentAccess at some places, but not for my_model.attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I'm wondering why Rails does often use the `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, but for example when using the `my_model.attributes` method, I get a normal hash:

```
my_model.attributes.class
=> Hash < Object
my_model.attributes.with_indifferent_access.class
=> ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess < Hash
```

Is there a specific reason/rule? Are there other "exceptions"?

Comment: Because it wasn't implemented this way. Maybe nobody had this idea (to return attribute hash with indifferent access)